# DependencyProperty doesn't find items in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, resourcedictionary

Currently i'm trying to mimic the behavior of the ContentControl Control in a FlowDocument environment. I like the ContentControl because it allows to display content in a different template based on the content's type. E.g.:

```
<ContentControl Content={Binding}/>
```

will use DataTemplates defined higer up in the XAML in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:Person}>...</DataType>
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:Pet}>...</DataType>
```

Now to copy this behavior for my FlowDocument alternative i started searching the internet. I the came across [Create Flexible UIs With Flow Documents And Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) which really helped a lot. As a start I altered the ItemsContent as follows:

```
public class TemplatedContent : Section
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(TemplatedContent), new PropertyMetadata(OnContentChanged));
    private static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Template", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(TemplatedContent), new PropertyMetadata(OnTemplateChanged));

    public TemplatedContent()
    {
        //Helpers.FixupDataContext(this);
        Loaded += TemplatedContent_Loaded;
    }

    private void TemplatedContent_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateContent(Template, Content);
    }

    public object Content
    {
        get { return GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public DataTemplate Template
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(TemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TemplateProperty, value); }
    }


    private void GenerateContent(DataTemplate template, object content)
    {
        Blocks.Clear();
        if (template != null && content != null)
        {
            FrameworkContentElement element = Helpers.LoadDataTemplate(template);
            element.DataContext = content;
            //Helpers.UnFixupDataContext(element);
            Blocks.Add(Helpers.ConvertToBlock(content, element));
        }
    }

    private void GenerateContent()
    {
        GenerateContent(Template, Content);
    }

    private void OnContentChanged(object newValue)
    {
        if (IsLoaded)
            GenerateContent(Template, newValue);
    }

    private void OnTemplateChanged(DataTemplate newValue)
    {
        if (IsLoaded)
            GenerateContent(newValue, Content);
    }

    private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TemplatedContent)d).OnContentChanged(e.NewValue);
    }

    private static void OnTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TemplatedContent)d).OnTemplateChanged((DataTemplate)e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

As you can see it's a verly basic peace of code and it works as expected when i use it in the following manner:

```
 <FlowDocument>
     <local:TemplatedContent Content={Binding}>
        <local:TemplatedContent.Template>
           <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:Person}>...</DataTemplate>
        </local:TemplatedContent.Template>
     </local:TemplatedContent>
 </FlowDocument>
```

This is all well but to support multiple templates for different content types i will need to define the DataTemplates in a resource dictionary:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <local:TemplatedContent Content={Binding}>
    </local:TemplatedContent>
</FlowDocument>
```

and higer up in a resource dictionary:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:Person}>...</DataTemplate>
```

Now, the TemplatedContent is unable to find the DataTemplate. How is this possible? If I understand the theory around DependencyProperty correctly it should look in the xaml tree for  entries that match the type of the content right? It doesn't. When setting a breakpoint on line:

```
private static void OnTemplateChanged
```

it's never called.

I hope you experts can help me further with this!

Lots of thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the template in your resource dictionary like so:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <FlowDocument.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
            <!-- Contents of template go here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlowDocument.Resources>
    <!-- document content here -->
</FlowDocument>
```

And the reference to your template is now done with a `StaticResource` markup extension:

```
<local:TemplateContent Content="{Binding}" Template="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! That does indeed work but it is no solution to my problem because I want to define a different template for each content type.

For example if content is of type Person I want to have a different template than when the content is of type House. By using a key for the template i'm not being able to do that as keys needs to be unique. (It's not allowed to have two DataTemplates with same key and different DataType in the Resources section). With Microsofts ContentControl it is possible to do it without key but I can't figure out how they do that... Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Why not use different keys? Also, when no key is specified an implicit key is generated by the XAML parser - the key will be an object of 'Type' and gets its value from TargetType (for Styles, ControlTemplates) or from DataType with DataTemplates.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the article you referred to does not support implicit data templates (no explicit key, just the DataType defined). Otherwise the solution would be to remove the x:Key attributes, and allow the framework to apply the templates correctly and automatically based on type. You could modify the code to support this fairly easily or you could create a default Style with the ItemTemplate set depending on your situation :)

Comment: Using different keys is not possible because those templates needs to be applied based on the Type of Content: _DataTemplate x:Key="MyPetTemplate"> and _DataType x:Key="MyPersonTemplate"> cannot be defined on the same _TemplatedControl Content="{Binding ObjectOfTypePetORPerson}" Template="{StaticResource HowDoISelectTheTemplateKeyHere}">.

Comment: Otherwise the solution would be to remove the x:Key attributes, and allow the framework to apply the templates correctly and automatically based on type. You could modify the code to support this fairly easily <==== That is i think exactly what i need, but I don't know where to start I looked through the source of Microsoft's ContentControl but I could not find any references to this automatic template selection. Do you have some keywords for this technique so that I can search for it?

Comment: I don't, but this would be a good topic for another question, these comments are running too long :)